# I get the following error when trying to create a mongodb connection in a test with jest. Error: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, jestjs

I get the following error when trying to create a mongodb connection in a test with jest.
Error: `Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongo`

test.js:
`

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

let plugin = this
let connection
let db
beforeAll(async () => {

    plugin.cfg = {
        mongo: {
            url: 'mongodb://mongo:27017/',
            dbwildduck: 'wildduck',
            dbwebsite: 'website',
        },
        redis: {
            host: 'redis',
            port: 6379,
            db: 3
        },
    }

    plugin.db = {
        wildduck: null,
        website: null,
        redis: null
    }

    try {
        connection = await MongoClient.connect(plugin.cfg.mongo.url);
        db = await connection.db(plugin.db.wildduck);

    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
})
```

`

when I debug the test, it gets to the first line inside the "try":
``connection = await MongoClient.connect(plugin.cfg.mongo.url);

it reaches that line and waits until the error mentioned above appears

I need to create this connection with mongodb to pass it by parameter to a method so that it can make the queries that it has inside

I need to create this connection with mongodb to pass it by parameter to a method so that it can make the queries that it has inside

Comment: Please try to add `directConnection=true` to your connection string

Comment: So ? URL: 'mongodb://mongo:27017/?directConnection=true'

Comment: Yes, with the creds to the db

Comment: `mongodb://root:password@mongo:27017/yourdbname?directConnection=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=replicaset&retryWrites=true`

Comment: I did it like this and it still gives the same error : mongodb://mongo:27017/wildduck?directConnection=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=replicaset&retryWrites=true

Comment: Please add your username and password

Comment: It is a local database, to which I always connect with the url as it is in the code, it does not have a username and password

Comment: `Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongo` is probably caused by DNS being unable to lookup `mongo`.

Comment: Then what do I do? Why does it work in my normal application and not in my tests?

Comment: Have you tried using the IP address of `mongo`?  If you use the IP address, there is no need for a DNS lookup.